# stop propagation

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, stoppropagation

I have a panel which opens and closes to display the menu by clicking an element with class `.open`. When I first click it, it's fine, the panel opens up. Once the panel is open,  I click on a menu Item and the panel closes.

The issue I am facing is that once the panel is closed after clicking on the menu item, I need to hit twice `.open` before the panel opens again.

I first run this:

```
$(".open").toggle(function(){
   $(".header").animate({height:"100%"},200);
   },function(){
        $(".header").animate({height:50},200);
});
```

This opens up a panel, with a menu, then when I click on a menu item i do:

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Is it an issue with propagation? Adding:

```
$(".navMore li a").on("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
```

Still leaves me with the same issue.

Comment: it is not clear what you're trying to achieve, or what is the problem you are facing. please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

The `click` event bubbles up in JQuery.  To prevent that you need to stop propagation from bubbling up on the lower element *and* stop the higher element's handler from firing.

In the `$('.open')` function you need to put the following:

```
$(".open").toggle( function( event ) {
    if( !$( event.target ).is("a") )
        {
            $(".header").animate({height:"100%"},200);
        }
},....);
```

Comment: .open isn't an "a" but a block

Comment: target is a property of the event that tells you what the element was that fired it.

Comment: still requires a double click :(